# Change the disabled status of a form element via Ajax

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form built with the Form API. I have a field which is, at first, disabled. I want to change the status of that field to enabled when the user selects another contiguous field.

I have a working example of changing the callback URL of Ajax complete of that field, so the form is making a kind of OnChange and working well, but for some reason I am not able to change the disabled status.

Code. Here the 2 elements, first brand and next the model, which is disabled at the beginning.

```
 $form['brand'] = array(
'#type' => 'select',
'#title' => t('Brand'),
'#options' => $brands,
'#default_value' => $brand,
'#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'hook_models_update',
    'wrapper' => 'models_wrapper',
    'progress' => array(
        'message' => '',
        'type' => 'throbber',
    ),
),
);

 $form['model'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Model'),
  //    '#description' => 'Please note available models change based on the brand selected.',
'#required' => FALSE,
'#autocomplete_path' => 'providers/autocomplete/' . $brand,
'#attributes' => array("placeholder" => t('Model')),
'#prefix' => '<div id="models_wrapper">',
'#suffix' => '</div>',
'#disabled' => TRUE,
);
```

Now the code for the "onChange" behaviour, which is a "throbber" called hook_models_update:

```
function hook_models_update($form, &$form_state) {
    unset($form_state['input']['model'], $form_state['values']['model']);
    $brand = $form_state['values']['brand'];
    $form['model']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'providers/autocomplete/' . $brand;
     $form['model']['#enabled'] = TRUE;
    // $form['model']["#disabled'] = FALSE
    return form_builder($form['#id'], $form['model'], $form_state);
} // function
```

I have tried with **#enabled** = TRUE and with **#disabled** = FALSE, with no successs.

Comment: I haven't seen `form_builder` used in an AJAX callback before, is that something you've seen in core/contrib? Not saying it's wrong, just never seen it. Usually you just return the element (`return $form['model'];`) It's definitely `'#disabled' => FALSE` BTW, there isn't an `#enabled` property

Comment: I don't recall where I saw it, it took me quite a lot to find it, and it is working perfectly in spite of all. I have solved the problem, I didn't find the right way of making the question, finally I found the solution, of course in this site.

Comment: can you post the answer?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure it'll work (if you return the element directly I'd wager the form system runs it through `form_builder` anyway). What was the problem out of interest?

Comment: It was done to refresh the autocomplete path of the form, so when the user select a brand, the autocomplete model URL changes dinamically (Javascript) so it only suggests those models of that selected brand. I didn't find more than this solution after quite a lot of time searching !

Comment: Adrian, I have updated the post to reflect the answer. It was already in this site but I hadn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here:

[Enable DropDown using Ajax Call](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54058/enable-dropdown-using-ajax-call)

The code finally gets this:

```
     function hook_models_update($form, &$form_state) {
         unset($form_state['input']['model'], $form_state['values']['model']);
         $brand = $form_state['values']['brand'];
         $form['model']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'providers/autocomplete/' . $brand;
         unset($form['model']["#attributes"]['disabled']);
         $form['model']['#disabled'] = FALSE;
         return form_builder($form['#id'], $form['model'], $form_state);
} // function
```

The trick lies in these two lines:

```
     unset($form['model']["#attributes"]['disabled']);
     $form['model']['#disabled'] = FALSE;
```

Apparently, there has to be an unset and not of #disabled, but #attributes - disabled. Why this is so convoluted is beyong my comprehension.

Comment: Good find! I'm pretty sure you've found a small bug in form API - `#attributes` should really be re-processed if there's a chance that property changes could have affected them

Comment: Well, I don't think I have found anything, cause the problem and solution was already in that post, I simply had a need. But I agree that if may be a small bug in the form API.