# Programmatically creating multivalue field with a button of add another

Tags: 7, entities

In the field ui, we can create a textfield with unlimited values. Which has button of add another, which when clicked added another field with a remove button.

I want the same functionality in my custom form. How will I create a textfield with unlimited values?
[image]

Comment: The examples module has such a form with detailed code and comments https://www.drupal.org/project/examples

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice article on how to do it using Form API http://rapiddg.com/blog/use-ajax-support-multiple-item-values-custom-drupal-7-forms

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to do the same in D8?

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax.
Here you have an example where an Ajax action will change the values of a select field.

[Change the disabled status of a form element via Ajax](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182831/change-the-disabled-status-of-a-form-element-via-ajax)

You can adapt the code in order to add fields instead of just replacing them. The method would be similar to that done with simple pure AJAX, but you will benefit from using the Drupal FORM API.